# Python Basics - First Project/Challenge

Tags: python

I'm extremely new to Python (and software programming/development in general).  I decided to use the scenario below as my first project.  The project includes 5 main personal challenges. Some of the challenges I have been able to complete (although probably not the most effecient way), and others I'm struggling with.  Any feedback you have on my approach and recommendations for improvement is GREATLY appreciated.

**Project Scenario** = "If I doubled my money each day for 100 days, how much would I end up with at day #100?  My starting amount on Day #1 is $1.00"

**1.) Challenge 1** - What is the net TOTAL after day 100 - (COMPLETED, I think, please correct me if I'm wrong)

```
days = 100
compound_rate = 2
print('compound_rate ** days) # 2 raised to the 100th

#==Result===
1267650600228229401496703205376
```

**2.) Challenge 2** - Print to screen the DAYS in the first column, and corresponding Daily Total in the second column.  - (COMPLETED, I think, please correct me if I'm wrong)

```
    compound_rate = 2                        
    days_range = list(range(101))               
    for x in days_range:
        print (str(x),(compound_rate ** int(x)))

# ===EXAMPLE Results
# 0 1
# 1 2
# 2 4
# 3 8
# 4 16
# 5 32
# 6 64
# 100 1267650600228229401496703205376
```

**3.) Challenge 3** - Write TOTAL result (after the 100 days) to an external txt file - (COMPLETED, I think, please correct me if I'm wrong)

```
compound_rate = 2                           
days_range = list(range(101))
hundred_days = (compound_rate ** 100)

textFile = open("calctest.txt", "w")
textFile.write(str(hundred_days))
textFile.close()
#===Result====
string of 1267650600228229401496703205376 --> written to my file 'calctest.txt'
```

**4.) Challenge 4** - Write the Calculated running DAILY Totals to an external txt file.  Column 1 will be the Day, and Column 2 will be the Amount.  So just like Challenge #2 but to an external file instead of screen

```
NEED HELP, I can't seem to figure this one out.
```

**5.) Challenge 5** - Somehow plot or chart the Daily Results (based on #4) - `NEED GUIDANCE.`

I appreciate everyone's feedback as I start on my personal Python journey!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**challenge 2**

This will work fine, but there's no need to write `list(range(101))`, you can just write `range(101)`. In fact, there's no need even to create a variable to store that, you can just do this:

```
for x in range(101):
    print("whatever you want to go here")
```

**challenge 3**

Again, this will work fine, but when writing to a file, it is normally best to use a `with` statement, this means that you don't need to close the file at the end, as python will take care of that. For example:

```
with open("calctest.txt", "w") as f:
    write(str(hundred_days))
```

**challenge 4**

Use a for loop as you did with challenge 2. Use "\n" to write a new line. Again do everything inside a with statement. e.g.

```
with open("calctest.txt", "w") as f:
    for x in range(101):
        f.write("something here \n").
```

(would write a file with 'something here ' written 101 times)

**challenge 5**

There is a python library called matplotlib, which I have never used, but I would suggest that would be where to go to in order to solve this task.

I hope this is of some help :)

Comment: Really appreciate you taking the time for the response Tim.  This is really helpful information.  I'm still trying to figure out the actual calculation that goes into f.write("something here \n") but will continue to try to work through it. I tried using the same calculation in challenge #2 but something seems off.

Comment: No worries. If you've found it helpful, please accept the answer or give it an upvote :) I would guess the problem is print() does a few things that write() doesn't. Firstly print() accepts many arguments, so you can just list the things it needs to print, it will also convert integers into strings automatically for you. write() only accepts one argument which must be a single string. So you will need to adapt your code sightly. To combine strings simply use '+' and to convert an integer into a string use str(). So for example `file.write(str(x)+str(compound_rate ** int(x)))`

Comment: Note also in challenge 2, the str() in `str(x)` is actually unnecessary since print() doesn't have to accept a string.

Comment: Also, `x` should already be an integer, so`int(x)` isn't actually need. `str(compound_rate**x)` should do.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use what you did in challenge 3 to open and close the ouput file.
- In between, you have to do what you did in challenge 2 to compute the data for each day.

  - In stead of writing the daily result to the stream, you will have to combine it into a string. After that, you can write that string to the file, exactly like you did in challenge 3.

Comment: Thanks for the response Peter!  I really appreciate it. Still trying to work through the details but I know it's part of the process.

Comment: Was able to get it going with the following.     '           
with open("calctest.txt", "w") as f:
    for x in range(101):
        # f.write("something here \n").
        f.write('Day#' + str(x) + '=' + '$' + (str(float(compound_rate ** int(x))))+ '\n')
'

Answer (score 0):

**Challenge One:**

This is the correct way.

```
days = 100
compound_rate = 2
print("Result after 100 days" + (compound_rate ** days))
```

**Challenge Two**

This is corrected.

```
compound_rate = 2                        
days_range = list(range(101))               
for x in days_range:
    print(x + (compound_rate ** x))
```

**Challenge Three**

This one is close but you didn't need to cast the result of hundred_days to a string as you can write the integer to a file and python doesn't care most of the time. Explicit casts need only to be worried about when using the data in some way other than simply printing it.

```
compound_rate = 2                           
days_range = list(range(101))
hundred_days = (compound_rate ** 100)

textFile = open("calctest.txt", "w")
textFile.write(hundred_days)
textFile.close()
```

**Challenge Four**

For this challenge, you will want to look into the python CSV module. You can write the data in two rows separated by commas very simply with this module.

**Challenge Five**

For this challenge, you will want to look into the python library matplotlib. This library will give you tools to work with the data in a graphical way.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for challenge 1 is as follows:

l = []

for a in range(0,100):

```
    b = 2 ** a

    l.append(b)
```

print("Total after 100 days", sum(l))

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, sys
import datetime
import time

#to get the current work directory, we use below os.getcwd()
print(os.getcwd())

#to get the list of files and folders in a path, we use os.listdir
print(os.listdir())

#to know the files inside a folder using path 
spath = (r'C:\Users\7char')
l = spath
print(os.listdir(l))

#converting a file format to other, ex: txt to py
path = r'C:\Users\7char'
print(os.listdir(path))
# after looking at the list of files, we choose to change 'rough.py' 'rough.txt'
os.chdir(path)
os.rename('rough.py','rough.txt')
#check whether the file has changed to new format
print(os.listdir(path))
#yes now the file is changed to new format


print(os.stat('rough.txt').st_size)
# by using os.stat function we can see the size of file (os.stat(file).sst_size)

path = r"C:\Users\7char\rough.txt"
datetime = os.path.getmtime(path)
moddatetime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(datetime))
print("Last Modified Time : ", moddatetime)

#differentiating b/w files and folders using - os.path.splitext
import os
path = r"C:\Users\7char\rough.txt"
dir(os.path)
files = os.listdir()
for file in files:
    print(os.path.splitext(file))

#moving a file from one folder to other (including moving with folders of a path or moving into subforlders)
import os
char_7 = r"C:\Users\7char"
cleardata = r"C:\Users\clearadata" 
operating = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\7char")
print(operating)
for i in operating:
    movefrom = os.path.join(char_7,i)
    moveto = os.path.join(cleardata,i) 
    print(movefrom,moveto)
    os.rename(movefrom,moveto)

#now moving files based on length of individual charecter (even / odd) to a specified path (even or odd).
import os

origin_path = r"C:\Users\movefilehere"
fivechar_path= r"C:\Users\5char"
sevenchar_path = r"C:\Users\7char"   

origin_path = os.listdir(origin_path)
    
for file_name in origin_pathlist:
    l = len(file_name)
    if l % 2 == 0:   
        evenfilepath = os.path.join(origin_path,file_name)
        newevenfilepath = os.path.join(fivechar_path,file_name)
        print(evenfilepath,newevenfilepath)
        os.rename(evenfilepath,newevenfilepath)        
    else:
        oddfilepath = os.path.join(origin_path,file_name)
        newoddfilepath = os.path.join(sevenchar_path,file_name)
        print(oddfilepath,newoddfilepath)
        os.rename(oddfilepath,newoddfilepath)
    

#finding the extension in a folder using isdir
import os

path = r"C:\Users\7char"
print(os.path.isdir(path))            

#how a many files .py and .txt (any files) in a folder
import os
from os.path import join, splitext
from glob import glob
from collections import Counter

path = r"C:\Users\7char"

c = Counter([splitext(i)[1][1:] for i in glob(join(path, '*'))])
for ext, count in c.most_common():
    print(ext, count)

#looking at the files and extensions, including the total of extensions.
import os
from os.path import join, splitext
from collections import defaultdict

path = r"C:\Users\7char"
c = defaultdict(int)
files = os.listdir(path)
for filenames in files:
    extension = os.path.splitext(filenames)[-1]
    c[extension]+=1
    print(os.path.splitext(filenames))
print(c,extension)

#getting list from range
list(range(4))

#break and continue statements and else clauses on loops
for n in range(2,10):
    for x in range(2,n):
        if n%x == 0:
            print(n,'equals',x, '*', n//x)
            break
    else:
        print(n, 'is a prime number')

#Dictionaries
#the dict() constructer builds dictionaries directly from sequences of key-value pairs
dict([('ad', 1212),('dasd', 2323),('grsfd',43324)])

#loop over two or more sequences at the same time, the entries can be paired with the zip() function.
questions = ['name', 'quest', 'favorite color']
answers = ['lancelot', 'the holy grail', 'blue']
for q, a in zip(questions, answers):
    print('What is your {0}?  It is {1}.'.format(q, a))

#Using set()
basket = ['apple', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'banana']
for f in sorted(set(basket)):
    print(f)
```